# Rig hierarchy breaking when Appending into a file

Tags: animation, rigging, rigid-body-simulation, append

I have a rig on a character and I have set up a simple soft body dynamic on it's hair geo (it's a carrot so it's hair is the green stalk). Works fine in it's original file, but when I bring it in (Append) to another file the hierarchy adds an empty that I don't see existing in my original. What's stranger to me is though the empty exists it seems to work fine when I Append it into a completely clean file, BUT, when I bring it into my main animation file with my other characters and set it doesn't work, the hair rig stays in place and doesn't follow the rest of the rig (easy to see in the videos). I am no rigger so the fact I almost got it working is a miracle. Can someone help me learn how to fix it so I can avoid these issues in the future?

I am including a few pics and video screengrabs below to help illustrate what I'm talking about.

-- I've dumbed down some of my files. I can not upload my larger animation file because of copyright reasons. I know that may make it difficult to troubleshoot but I'm hopeful it's something obvious to a seasoned rigger in my original file that will fix it.--

Here is my carrot's Blender file:

[image]

Here is an image of the original file's hierarchy:
[image]

And here is how it looks when I Append it into a clean Blender file, notice the hierarchy has changed and it's added an Empty:
[image]

And here is the video of it working just fine in it's original file:
[It works!](https://youtu.be/z57_FulkLYc)

And here it is NOT working after Appending it to my full animation file:
[It doesn't work... :(](https://youtu.be/NJx1x5pqVfU)

Comment: Is there any way to help get some more exposure to this question? Did I not include enough information?

Comment: Helloooooo? Is anyone out there? .......... there?  ..................... there? ...........................